# How do I compare class type of two different variables for equality?

Tags: matlab, matrix, switch-statement, equality

I am trying to make a statement using switch case block and I want to know how thats possible with 2 variables?

I am supposed to add variables a and b if the case is 'double' but how would I do that if:

```
a = [1 2 3 4]
b = [2 1 3 1]
?
```

So far I was thinking of doing this.

```
a = [1 2 3 4]
b = [2 1 3 1]
c = class (a)
d = class (b)
e = c == d

switch blah
       case 'double'
       a + b
       case 'logical'
       a & b
       otherwise
       disp ('None')


end
```

and so on

Now I need a switch and case block to create a scenario where if our switch x has the case 'double' (class type) it will add variables a and b.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use `if` statements instead and do something with `isequal` like

```
>> isequal(class(a), class(b))
ans = 

     1
```

We can then use this in an `if` statement like

```
a = [1 2 3 4];
b = [2 1 3 1];

if isequal(class(a), class(b)) && isequal(class(a), 'double')
    a + b
end
```

`switch` statements are meant for scenarios where you have multiple `case`'s not just 1.

However, as only `switch` statements can be used you can also use multiple `switch` statements to check both variables have the same `class`

```
a = [1 2 3 4];
b = [2 1 3 1];

switch class(a)
    case 'double'
        switch class(b)
            case 'double'
                a + b
        end
    case 'logical'
        switch class(b)
            case 'logical'
                a & b
        end
end
```

Comment: I have already completed this using an if block I need to find a way to do this using switch-case now :/ Any ideas?

Comment: @user2924450 Yes, sorry I was still adding stuff to my answer about `switch` when you commented. Does that help?

Comment: The problem is, using an if statement can solve a lot of issues but i cant use it at all for this question which is why i was looking for a way to do it with just switch and case. Apparently it is possible by comparing the class type of variable a and b for equality. I just dont know how.

Comment: @user2924450 I've done it now using only `switch` statements. Is that what you want now?

Comment: Yes Thank You so much